Making an image scale down on mobile with next/Image
I am using next/Image along with tailwind to render an image which acts as a banner. It spans the entire width of its parent, which is the entire page width.
The issue I am having is that the image looks squished and not properly proportioned on mobile, which I am looking to fix. I have tried solutions from two other solutions on this site (here and here), but nothing ever worked for me.
I suspect it may be the height that is set on the parent div, which I am open to changing if that would aid in fixing my issue.


      <div className="relative w-full h-[476px]">
  <Image src="/banner.jpg" alt="Banner" fill />
</div>




You can change the object-fit properties to make it scale properly.

You can achieve this in CSS by using object-fit which works for img elements. You can try object-fit: cover; or object-fit: contain; whichever works best for your use case.
